# PayPal Buy Now Button - Pre-populate Credit Card

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to make the Buy Now page open up the credit card form straight away.

Currently it's buried underneath the "pay with paypal" option that hardly any of my customers want to use. They have to click the tab at the bottom right. It's a very very poorly designed page and plays havoc with my conversion rates.

Could I for example pre-populate the credit card details in my buy now button so that the credit card form would come up initially?

Answer (score 2):

With buttons it is not possible as the form is hosted by PayPal. You may want to look into other integration methods at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ where you host the form that holds payment info.

See this for an example

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Comment: Sadly that requires HTTPS which they've made almost impossible to implement on a website. I'm very experienced in PHP, CSS, Jquery, SQL and so forth. But I've never been able to make my website HTTPS.....just another monopoly thing they've created.

Comment: HTTPS is fairly easy to setup and you don't need to enable for entire web site; just the pages the collect and process card data. You just need to get an so certificate and follow one of the many tutorials. This is for Apache https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm